# Getting Different results on Each Iteration using Long Short Term Memory[LSTM] for text classification

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, text-classification

> I am using LTSM Deep-learning  technique to classify my text, First i am  dividing them into text and lables using panda library and  making their tokens and then dividing them into into training and text data sets,whenever i runs the code, i get different results which varies from (80 to 100)percent.
> Here is my code,

```
   tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_NB_WORDS, filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~', 
   lower=True)
   tokenizer.fit_on_texts(trainDF['texts'])
   word_index = tokenizer.word_index
    print('Found %s unique tokens.' % len(word_index))


  X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(trainDF['texts'])

  X = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
  print('Shape of data tensor:', X.shape)

 Y = pd.get_dummies(trainDF['label'])
 print('Shape of label tensor:', Y.shape)


 X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size = 0.10, random_state = 42)
 print(X_train.shape,Y_train.shape)
 print(X_test.shape,Y_test.shape)


 model = Sequential()
 model.add(Embedding(MAX_NB_WORDS, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=X.shape[1]))
 model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.2))
 model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))

 variables_for_classification=6 #change it as per your number of categories

 model.add(Dense(variables_for_classification, activation='softmax'))
 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
 print(model.summary())


 epochs = 5
batch_size = 64
 history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=epochs, 
 batch_size=batch_size,validation_split=0.1,callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3, 
min_delta=0.0001)])
accr = model.evaluate(X_test,Y_test)
print('Test set\n  Loss: {:0.3f}\n  Accuracy: {:0.3f}'.format(accr[0],accr[1]))
```

> Train on 794 samples, validate on 89 samples
> Epoch 1/5
> 794/794 [==============================] - 19s 24ms/step - loss: 1.6401 - accuracy: 0.6297 - val_loss: 0.9098 - val_accuracy: 0.5843
> Epoch 2/5
> 794/794 [==============================] - 16s 20ms/step - loss: 0.8365 - accuracy: 0.7166 - val_loss: 0.7487 - val_accuracy: 0.7753
> Epoch 3/5
> 794/794 [==============================] - 16s 20ms/step - loss: 0.7093 - accuracy: 0.8401 - val_loss: 0.6519 - val_accuracy: 0.8652
> Epoch 4/5
> 794/794 [==============================] - 16s 20ms/step - loss: 0.5857 - accuracy: 0.8829 - val_loss: 0.4935 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
> Epoch 5/5
> 794/794 [==============================] - 16s 20ms/step - loss: 0.4248 - accuracy: 0.9345 - val_loss: 0.3512 - val_accuracy: 0.8652
> 99/99 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
> Test set
> Loss: 0.348
> Accuracy: 0.869
> in the last run accuracy was 100 percent.